# PHP login not working - user still sees the login form on protected pages after logging in

Tags: php, forms, authentication

------ SOLVED ------
Hi everyone, I have now solved this issue and it was my inexperience and trying to be clever that caused this issue, as you can also see from the comments below the issue was in my .htaccess file. I had put `RewriteRule ^admin adminlogin.php` so this was changing any page containing admin back to adminlogin.php

------ORIGINAL QUESTION------
Im trying to get a simple login script working on a website. It is coded in php and it is as follows:

adminlogin:

```
<div class="login">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<table width="379px" border="0px" cellpadding="3px" cellspacing="1px">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Admin Login</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78px">Username</td>
<td width="6px">:</td>
<td width="294px"><input name="myusername" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

checklogin.php:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="Logins"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE UN='$myusername' and PWD=md5('$mypassword')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file “adminloginsuccess.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $myusername;
header('location:adminhome.php');
}
else {
header('location:adminloginretry.php');
}
?>
```

adminhome.php:

```
<?php $thisPage="Admin Home";
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
header("location:adminlogin.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/meta.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php'); ?>
<div id="links">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/links.php'); ?>
</div><!--close links-->
</div><!--close header-->
<div id="sidebar">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/sidebarimage.php'); ?>
</div><!--close sidebar-->
<div id="content">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/adminhomecontent.php'); ?>
</div><!--close content-->
<div id="extra" align="center">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/fblb.php'); ?>
</div><!--close extra-->
<div id="footer">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div><!--close footer-->
</div><!--close container-->
</div><!--close wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

adminhomecontent.php:

```
You Have Successfully Logged In.<br>
<a href="logout.php">Log Out </a>
```

Now for some reason when I go and log in, I am redirected and the address bar says www.gemma-hyde-fashion-sketches.co.cc/adminhome.php but still shows the login form, and if I view the source I see the source for adminlogin.php.

I am new to PHP, could anybody assist, I found this code online so have tried myself to understand it as fully as I can

------EDIT------
I have created a log in for stackoverflow users. If you head over to www.gemma-hyde-fashion-sketches.co.cc/adminlogin.php and use the username stackoverflow and the password stackoverflow you should see the same results i'm getting (there isnt actually anything in the admin area at this time anyway)

------EDIT FOR JUDDA------
Yes what I mean is that if I log in, the address bar shows: http://www.gemma-hyde-fashion-sketches.co.cc/adminhome.php which is what i expected to be redirected to. However if i right click and view source I see

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Gemma Hyde Fashion Sketches | Admin Login</title> 
<meta name="title" content="Gemma Hyde Fashion Sketches | Admin Login" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Admin Login,  gemma hyde fashion sketches, fashion, fashion design, fashion sketches, fashion design sketches, clothes design sketches" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

which is the same as what the adminlogin.php page would show, this makes me think that this section at the top of adminhome.php:

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
header("location:adminlogin.php");
}
```

Is just redirecting because it cannot pick up that it is logged in.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Why do you quote your variables? `"$host"` etc should be `$host`

Comment: @ThiefMaster I do not know, as mentioned I am new to PHP and this code was taken from a tutorial online.

Comment: I have just checked the uploaded site using the stackoverflow account. Can you try to keep the adminhome more simple (sripped down). Maybe so it contains just <p>logged in</p>. So we just eliminate your includes as part of the problem

Comment: @boug I did that for you, but it still seems to redirect to adminlogin.php even though that address bar still shows adminhome.php

Comment: try going to http://www.gemma-hyde-fashion-sketches.co.cc/adminhome.php directly without logging in. you will see that it shows the login page. This might be a case of mistaken files. Make sure that the adminlogin.php has the right code in it and not just a copy of the login page.

Comment: @boug from what I can see from the code I used this is because of the php code at the top that checks for the session, it cant pick that up when you go directly so it shows the login screen. I have checked and double checked the naming and inclusions of the files and they are all the correct ones

Comment: ok this might be minor point but can you ensure that location is Location with a capital L and that is a space between : and page name e.g `header("Location: adminlogin.php");`

Comment: @boug just tried that and it hasn't made a change

Comment: this is an interesting problem

Comment: by the way, if anyone wants to view the php configuration it is available at www.gemma-hyde-fashion-sketches.co.cc/phpinfo.php

Comment: can you try adding print_r($_SESSION) just after session_start line in adminhome.php so we can see what we have inside the sessions variables

Comment: Can we see the source of meta.php and header.php?  The header that you have there (`header("location: adminlogin.php");`) isn't causing the issue because you would be physically redirected (i.e. a new url in the browser) if you were actually being redirected.

Comment: Hi Guy's thank you all so much for your help, I have just realised that it was something that I was doing. I came across it by trial and error. In my .htaccess file I was using `RewriteRule ^admin adminlogin.php` this was changing any page with admin, to adminlogin.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this issue and it was my inexperience and trying to be clever that caused this issue, as you can also see from the comments below the issue was in my .htaccess file. I had put `RewriteRule ^admin adminlogin.php` so this was changing any page containing admin back to adminlogin.php

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like PHP isn't running on the file if you are able to see the actual PHP for it (which I understand from the statement "and if I view the source I see the source for adminlogin.php").  Do other PHP pages work (i.e. `<?php phpinfo();?>`)?

Comment: sorry php is running, i mean i see the generated output, therefore I can see the page title etc which is generated automatically from the meta.php file

Comment: Can you explain the quote that I made from you a bit further because I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect the session is not set check that in adminhome.php

Change this code

```
Session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
header("location:adminlogin.php");
```

to this

```
Session_start();
 exit(var_dump($_SESSION));
```